# Find all vectors $v$ in $\mathbb{F}_5^2$ such that...

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

**Exercise** Find all vectors $v$ in $\mathbb{F}_5^2$ such that

$$2v + \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}$$

Note: $\mathbb{F}_5$ is the finite field with $5$ elements.

---

*Attempt*. For simplicity, we treat $\mathbb{F}_5^2$ as $\mathbb{Z}_5^2$. Recall that

$$\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_5 = \{(x,y) : x,y \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}\}$$

Again,

$$2v+\begin{bmatrix}
3 \\ 4
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 3
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$2v = \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 3
\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}
3 \\ 4
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$2v = \begin{bmatrix}
-2 \\ -1
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$v = \frac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix}
-2 \\ -1
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$v = \begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\ -0.5
\end{bmatrix}$$

---

I do not know where to proceed from here. I know that the $-1$ in $\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ -0.5 \end{bmatrix}$ can be treated as $-1 \mod 5 \equiv 4 \mod 5$, but I'm not sure what to make of the $-0.5$. Am I merely allowed to say $-0.5 \mod 5 \equiv 4.5 \mod 5$?

**Answer Guess:**

$$v \equiv \begin{bmatrix} 4\\ 4.5 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: While the multiplicative inverse $2^{-1}$ is $\frac12$ in the rational numbers, that quantity doesn't exist in $\Bbb Z_5$. What is $2^{-1}$ in $\Bbb Z_5$?

Comment: By multiplicative inverse, are we attempting to obtain the multiplicative identity, i.e. $2 \circ 2^{-1} = 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've gotten it to
$$2v=\begin{bmatrix}-2\\-1\end{bmatrix},$$
you need to solve the equations $2x=-2$ and $2y=-1$ in $\mathbb F_5$. The first is easy, giving $x=-1\equiv 4\pmod 5$. For the second, if we want to find $y\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ (as we usually write elements of $\mathbb F_5$), we need to determine which of these satisfies $5\mid 2y+1$, as an integer. Which one is it?

Comment: Why must we consider $5 \mid 2y +1$? Why does it not suffice to do with $y$ what we did with $x$? Is it because $y= - \frac{1}{2}$ does not make sense in $\mathbb{Z}_5$?

Comment: Actually, $-\frac{1}{2}$ makes perfect sense in $\Bbb{Z}_5$: it is the additive inverse of the multiplicative inverse of $2$. The issue is that it's not simplified. The additive inverse of the multiplicative inverse of $2$ should be one of the $5$ elements of $\Bbb{Z}_5$, so you need to figure out which one it is.